# Handling DisambiguationError?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except, pywikibot

I'm using the `wikipedia` library and I want to handle the `DisambiguationError` as an exception.  My first try was

```
try:
     wikipedia.page('equipment') # could be any ambiguous term
except DisambiguationError:
     pass
```

During execution line 3 isn't reached.  A more general question is: how can I find the error type for a library-specific class like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
import wikipedia

try:
    wikipedia.page('equipment')
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    print("Error: {0}".format(e))
```

Regarding to your more general question `how can I find the error type for a library-specific class like this?`, my trick is actually quite simple, I tend to capture Exception and then just printing the `__class__`, that way I'll know what specific Exception I need to capture.

One example of figuring out which specific exception to capture here:

```
try:
    0/0
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception.__class__: {0}".format(e.__class__))
```

This would print `Exception.__class__: <type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>`, so I knew `exceptions.ZeroDivisionError` would be the exact Exception to deal with instead of something more generic

Comment: @Jason Yeah, you're right, I've edited my code to become more clear for other people ;-)

Comment: Ha, I just realized I didn't read carefully enough and your code was pretty clear in the first place.  I guess extra clarity can't hurt though!